# How to run each client on new thread with ExecutorService Java?

Tags: java, http, java.util.concurrent

I am implementing HTTP server on vanilla Java. And I try to use ExecutorService.
First request is successful in browser, but second one has endless loading.

Code of my `start()` method of server:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
        this.server = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        client = this.server.accept();
        while (true) {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                Socket cs = client;
                try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream());
                     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()))
                ) {
                    // write server http headers response
                    out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n");
                    out.print("Content-Type: text/plain\n");
                    out.print("Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.5\n");
//                    out.print("Connection: close\n");
                    out.print("\n");

                    String data;
                    // read client request
                    while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (data.length() == 0) {
                            out.write("EOF(End of file)");
                            break;
                        }
                        // write back to client its request as response body.
                        out.write(data + "\n");
                    }
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    cs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use this code i hope it's going to help you

after catch use finally to close in

```
 BufferedReader objReader = null;
  try {
   String strCurrentLine;

   objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\DukesDiary.txt"));

   while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {

    System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
   }

  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();

  } finally {

   try {
    if (objReader != null)
     objReader.close();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
```

update

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"),true);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to implement my own server. I want to find out my mistake in the code

Comment: in the while loop  ****>>> use this while like this ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)  this is your mistake >>>>(data = in.readLine()) != null

Comment: But what is `buffer` ?

Comment: you dont need the buffer in while loop just replace null with  != -1 ... check if it works tell me!!

Comment: No I cannot != -1, because my data is String

Comment: use code above after while loop out and in never close so use finaly to flush or close input and ouput  stream and also check if null or not

Comment: but as I know try-with-resources is best practice, no?

Comment: look at the code above and move in,close and out.close on finally and also check in and and out not nulll..

Comment: if you want to your server never down you must use but if you check the in or out null you dont need to use try catch again

Comment: I cannot add to finally out, in and close it, because lambda requires final variables

Comment: use the auto flush  lock at the update code.. your problem is PrintWriter never flush

Comment: Thank you, I`ll try